# How to delete the contents of a buffer by name

Tags: buffers, gdb, deletion

For example in gdb mode, there is a buffer named `*input/output of <program name>*`, that I want to clear each time I press `C-c l`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you don't know the exact name of the buffer, you need to call [`buffer-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Buffer-List.html#index-buffer_002dlist-2582) to obtain the list of buffers and filter the result to only act on the desired buffer(s).

Untested code:

```lisp
(defun erase-buffers-matching (regexp)
  "Erase the content of all buffers whose name matches REGEXP."
  (interactive "sErase buffers matching: ")
  (save-match-data
    (mapc (lambda (buffer)
            (cond
             ((not (string-match regexp (buffer-name buffer))))
             ((and (buffer-file-name buffer) (buffer-modified-p buffer))
              (message "Skipping buffer %s with unsaved data" (buffer-name buffer))
             (t
              (with-current-buffer buffer
                (erase-buffer)))))
          (buffer-list))))
```

**For the specific case of the GDB program output buffer**, GDB keeps track of it. It's the `gdb-inferior-io` buffer.

```lisp
(defun erase-gdb-inferior-io-buffer ()
  (interactive)
  (with-current-buffer (gdb-get-buffer 'gdb-inferior-io)
    (erase-buffer)))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c l") 'erase-gdb-inferior-io-buffer)
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is something you want to do often, you could define a function for it in your .emacs file. Otherwise you could type it out in *scratch*, evaluate it and then assign it a  key binding?

You could try:

```
(defun my/clear_buffer ()
  (interactive) 
  (let ((tmp (buffer-name)))
  (if (get-buffer "<buffer name>")              ;; check if buffer exists
      (progn (switch-to-buffer "<buffer name>") ;; switch to the buffer
         (erase-buffer)                         ;; erase it
         (switch-to-buffer tmp)))))             ;; switch back
```

Comment: The thing is that <buffer name> is not constant, it changes with the program being debugged. Is there a way to get the buffer by regexp instead? so I can use only the substring `*input/output of  ` with `get-buffer`?

Comment: [Never use `switch-to-buffer` to act on a buffer](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Switching-Buffers.html#Switching-Buffers). It's for changing which buffer is displayed on a window. To act on a buffer from Lisp code, use `with-current-buffer`, or for more complex cases `save-excursion` and `set-buffer`.